# Value of Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form. **I'm trying get the value of the option selected, but my code does not work.**

Form:

```
<form action="javascript:function()" method="POST" id="formulario">
                        <select class="selectpicker" id="cidade"> <option value "1"> Adamantina  </option>
                                                                                                                    <option value "2"> Adolfo  </option>
                                                                                                                    <option value "3"> Aguaí  </option>
                                                                                                                    <option value "4"> Águas da Prata  </option>

                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="checkboxes">Selecione as opções: Mandioca para industria Área em produção</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes-0">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="2000" id="mans_00" value="mans_ins_area_00">
                              2000
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes-1">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="2005" id="mans_05" value="mans_ins_area_05">
                              2005
                            </label>
                                <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes-1">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="2010" id="mans_10" value="mans_ins_area_10">
                              2010
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button id="enviar_grafico" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary"> Enviar</button>
                    </form>
```

Select:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="cidadee"> <?php $cidades=lista_cidades($conexao);
                                                                foreach($cidades as $cidade): ?>
                                                                <option value "<?= $cidade['dados_cidades_id'] ?>"> <?= $cidade['Municipio']; ?>  </option>
                                                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </select>
```

My JavaScript(using jQuery):

```
(function () {
$("#formulario").submit(function() {
    var cidadee = $( "#cidadee:selected" ).val();
    var mans_00 = $('#mans_00:checked').val();
    var mans_05 = $('#mans_05:checked').val();
    var mans_10 = $('#mans_10:checked').val();
    var registro;
    var param_1;
    console.log(cidadee);
    });
});
```

I tried `var cidade = $( "#cidade option:selected" ).val();` also, but
in my web browser when I submit the form, it still shows up empty.

Comment: First of, you only need `$("#cidade").val()` as there can only be one value for your select box. Second, please post the code generated by PHP and not the php code itself - that way we can easily reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#cidade").children("option:selected").val();
$("#cidade").children("option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually only need `$('#cidadee').val()` to retrieve the value selected.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a select box, you simply ask for it, and nothing more:

```
$("#cidade").val();
```

A select box can only have *one value* selected, so the above should work. Checkboxes can be `:checked`, radio buttons can be `:selected`, but select boxes act like text boxes with a predetermined list of `val`s.

Comment: I edited only with html, because doesn't work in this form.
the only thing I could do was catch the "text" using the prop text.
See please

Comment: Are you saying your select box _actually_ contains the `<?php` tags? Because if your script isnt actually running (aka interpreted as html itself) then it wont work because your html in **invalid**. Otherwise this should work on _any_ select element. I also want to add that none of your script should actually work, you are misusing :`selected` and `:checked` for value fetching methods...